# How to get number of facebook likes from an individual app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've done some searching and can't seem to find an answer to this.  I'd like to find out how many Facebook likes came from a specific app and not the overall fan page itself.

Set up:

I have a "fan page" for a company that I manage. This company runs promotions from time to time and usually do so through a FB app that is attached to the fan page.  These apps vary in type, but usually are just a page tab app hosted on heroku with a like gate.

Obviously, a like on the like gate results in a like for the fan page.  Is there any way to find out how many likes came from that specific like gate / page tab app?  FB Insights shows "where likes came from" but nothing I've found lists individual apps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though from `page_fans_by_like_source_unique` you can get a lot of metrics, there isn't currently one to differentiate between tabs.

The approach I'm currently using, is tracking on my app side, saving the information into a database, because both like and unlike events refresh the app iframe, with a new signed_request. The logic is the one described [by @dleavitt here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7355522/445887)

Sources: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/#like_sources